# How do I create a scope to filter services by customer_category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables/models: customers and services, and I'm developing a service filter.

- The relationship between this two tables: a customer 'has many' services, and a service 'belongs to' a customer.
- The service filter html slim code:

```html
.col-sm-6
    - options_for_customer_select = Customer.uniq.order('name ASC').pluck(:name, :id)
    = label_tag :q, 'Customer:'
    = select_tag :by_customer_id, options_for_select(options_for_customer_select, params[:by_customer_id])
```

- The customer category scope: (code needs change)

```html
    scope :by_customer_category, -> customer_id { where("customer_id in ?", customer_id) }
```

In the customer category select input (in the filter), I want to list by the name of customer category and use the customer_id to filter the services that have the specifics customers.

How can I write Ruby/Rails code to something like that in SQL: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM`services`WHERE (customer_id in (1, 2, 3))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I write Ruby/Rails code to something like that in SQL: SELECT
>   COUNT(*) FROM services WHERE (customer_id in (1, 2, 3))?

This is how you can do that:

```
Service.where(customer_id: [1,2,3]).count
```

If you want your scope to do that, you must use this:

```
scope :scope_name, -> (customer_ids){where(customer_id: customer_ids)}
```

Your original scope will also work if you replace the `?` in the `where` params with `(?)`:

```
scope :scope_name, -> (customer_ids){where("customer_id IN (?)", customer_ids)}
```

And then you could do:

```
Service.scope_name([1,2,3]).count
```

Comment: But when I run the scope like that: `Service.by_customer_category([1, 2, 3])`, I got: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM services WHERE (customer_id in 1, 2, 3)` without the "()", so it doesn't work